# A connected, simple, 3 regular graph is 2-connected

Tags: graph-theory, graph-connectivity

I understand intuitively that it needs to be the case but don’t know how to prove it. In fact, I think it can be done through a contradiction. We assume G is not 2 connected. But not sure what to do after that, help? Also please consider me a newbie. Be intuitive and concise plz

Comment: Presumably you know all the definitions. Can you say what "not 2 connected" means? I'm talking about a sentence like "it means there are two vertices $v$ and $w$ with the property that..." or "it means that for every edge $e$, there's a vertex ..." That's the usual first step in a contradiction proof -- a simple rewrite of the contradiction hypothesis.

Answer (score 2):

Take three copies of the graph shown below, and identify the three points `o` to a single vertex; the resulting graph on $16$ vertices is connected, $3$-regular, and not $2$-connected: removing the vertex `o` disconnects it.

```
                 o
                 |
                 *
                / \
               /   \
              *——*——*
               \ | /
                \|/
                 *
```

Comment: Thanks I think that does it

Comment: @JohnMax: You’re welcome. Note that this is actually a counterexample to the proposed result.

Comment: Yes. I somehow thought k regular graph always contain k-1 regular graph but I didn’t think of a case k - 1 regular graph contained in the original can be disconnected